# Every monoid admits a surjection from a free monoid?

Tags: category-theory, monoid

How can I show that every monoid $M$ admits a surjection from a free monoid $F(X) \rightarrow M$ ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Take $X = M$ and extend the identity map.